# NuGet allowOverrideExistingPackageOnPush Stops Symbol Packages Being Published

Tags: nuget-package, debug-symbols, nuget-server

Version 2.8 of NuGet server now provides a flag in the web.config called `allowOverrideExistingPackageOnPush` which allows you to decide if you want existing package versions to be overwritten. We decided to set this to false on our internal repository because we didn't want existing packages being accidentally overwritten. However, now when I do a pack and push using the `-Symbols` flag, the `push` command will successfully publish the nuget package but when it tries to publish the symbols, it only uses the first part of the package name up to the end of the version number. This means that it fails to publish the symbols package as it believes that the package already exists.

I have yet to find any information or bug reports via googling, and for the package I am writing now I can dispense with symbols, but we need a longer term solution which will allow us to publish symbols and disallow overwriting.

Has anyone encountered this, and if so have you found a way round this (other than not publishing symbols or allowing overwriting)? This has been sapping time which I can't really spare.

Comment: Here I am, four years later, facing the same problem. Did you end up solving this somehow?

Comment: Sadly not as far as I recall. That was many contracts ago and I don't think I touched NuGet again! I suspected that we were probably trying to use it incorrectly but we obviously worked around it somehow - I just don't remember how, sorry.

Comment: I just ended up enabling `allowOverrideExistingPackageOnPush` since that is acceptable for our workflow. Thank you for taking the time to reply.